# Why isn't SplitArgument working as expected here?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xparse

I'm trying to define macros to set the size and position of TikZ nodes based on the text that is supposed to go into them. Because there are multiple similar but not identical nodes of varying complexity, I tried to extract their commonalities into an internal macro, but somehow `xparse`'s `\SplitArgument` isn't working as expected.

Here's an MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newsavebox\testTempBox
\NewDocumentCommand{\commonFunction}{+m}{%
    \begin{lrbox}{\testTempBox}%
    \begin{varwidth}{6cm}%
        #1%
    \end{varwidth}%
    \end{lrbox}%
    \the\wd\testTempBox;\the\ht\testTempBox
    %Function is simplified a lot; has more inputs and outputs
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\variationA}{+m}{%
    \variationAInternal{#1}{\commonFunction{#1}}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\variationAInternal}{+m >{\SplitArgument{1}{;}}m}{%
    \variationAInternalInternal{#1}#2\\
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\variationAInternalInternal}{m m m}{%
    #2%
    %\node[trapezium, ...] at (#4, #5) {\parbox{#3}{\centering #1}};
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\variationB}{+m}{%
    \variationBInternal{#1}{\commonFunction{#1}}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\variationBInternal}{+m >{\SplitArgument{1}{;}}m}{%
    #2
    %\node[rectangle, ...] at (#4,#5) {\parbox{#3}{\centering #1}};
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\variationA{Test 1:\\Some Test}\\
\variationB{Test 2:\\Second Test}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Failed Splitting]

I also tried using identifiers and `\csname` like this, and I have no idea why the height works but the widths don't:

```latex
\documentclass[a7paper,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\newsavebox\tmpBox
\NewDocumentCommand{\commonFunction}{m +m}{%
    %still less complex than the original
    \expandafter\newsavebox\csname box#1\endcsname%
    \begin{lrbox}{\csname box#1\endcsname}
    \begin{varwidth}{6cm}
        #2
    \end{varwidth}
    \end{lrbox}
    \expandafter\newlength\csname tw#1\endcsname%
    \expandafter\newlength\csname w#1\endcsname%
    \expandafter\newlength\csname h#1\endcsname%
    \expandafter\setlength\csname tw#1\endcsname{\expandafter\wd\csname box#1\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\setlength\csname w#1\endcsname{\dimexpr\expandafter\wd\csname box#1\endcsname + 4ex\relax}%
    \expandafter\setlength\csname h#1\endcsname{\dimexpr\expandafter\ht\csname box#1\endcsname + 2ex\relax}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\startstop}{m +m}{%
    \commonFunction{#1}{#2}%
    \node[draw, rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=\csname w#1\endcsname, minimum height=\csname h#1\endcsname, fill=red!30] at (0,0) {\parbox{\csname tw#1\endcsname}{\centering #2}};
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\startstop{FlowStart}{Start:\\Test}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Failed csname]

Comment: Your second argument to `\variationAInternal` is `\commonFunction{Test 1:\\Some Test}`. There's no `;` in it. Do the `lrbox` before `\variationAInternal` and then forward the `\the`s to the internal functions (and then you can already use normal `m`s.

Comment: How do I make that second Argument into the **output** of `\commonFunction{Test 1:\\Some Test}` instead?

Comment: TeX doesn't work like functions in programming language. You also won't be able to fully expand `\commonFunction` (even if it is defined via `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`) because it simply is not fully expandable (the closes you get to normal functions). Check the tag [tag:expansion] for more on this concept.

Comment: I'd be interested in your usecase on the TikZ side of things. The `minimum width`/ `height` gets checked after the `inner sep`s gets added to the dimension of the text. Nodes will always be at least as big as its text (unless you do something against it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second argument to `\variationAInternal` is `\commonFunction{Test 1:\\Some Test}`. There's no `;` in it.

Without knowing how complex your actual usecase gets, I'd do the `lrbox` before `\variationAInternal` and then forward the `\the`s to the internal functions (and then you can already use normal `m`s).

The `\exp_args:Nnff` does nothing but `f`ully expands its third and fourth argument before forwarding it to its first argument. (This may not really be necessary but who knows what else is happening with `\testTempBox` until `\variationAInternal` accesses its dimensions.)

Since PGF/TikZ uninstalls your normal font inside of the pictures (and reinstalls them for nodes or `\pgftext`) you will need to use `\pgfutil@selectfont` at the start of the `lrbox` or the `varwidth` environment. This obviously will ignore any font selection for the node but will pickup any other changes to fonts that were done before `\variationA`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\newsavebox\testTempBox

\makeatletter % for \pgfutil@selectfont
\NewDocumentCommand{\commonFunction}{+m}{%
    \begin{lrbox}{\testTempBox}%
    \begin{varwidth}{6cm}%
        \pgfutil@selectfont#1%
    \end{varwidth}%
    \end{lrbox}%
    %Function is simplified a lot; has more inputs and outputs
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOn % for \exp_args
\NewDocumentCommand{\variationA}{+m}{
    \commonFunction{#1}
    \exp_args:Nnff \variationAInternal { #1 } % no expand
                                       { \the\wd\testTempBox } % fully expand
                                       { \the\ht\testTempBox } % fully expand
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\NewDocumentCommand{\variationAInternal}{+m m m }{
    \node[draw, align=center,
      label={[node font=\tiny,xscale=.5]#2${}\times{}$#3}]{#1};
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\variationA{Test 1:\\Some Test}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks, `\exp_args` is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Nvm, doesn't work inside `tikzpicture`

Comment: Because it's not inside a node. TikZ install a null font (see the log) on purpose. You will need `\pgfutil@selectfont` before `#1` inside of `\commonFunction` or do all this inside a node (or a `\pgftext`?).

Comment: Thanks. In combination with your updated code example I finally got it to work as intended!

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{>{\SplitArgument{;}{1}}m}{...#1...}
```

a call such as

```
\foo{a;b}
```

would result in

```
...{a}{b}...
```

whereas

```
\foo{a}
```

would result in

```
...{a}{-NoValue-}...
```

Usually one has

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{>{\SplitArgument{;}{1}}m}{%
  ...\fooaux#1...%
}
```

where `\fooaux` is a command with two mandatory arguments where you check with `\IfNoValueTF{#2}` whether `-NoValue-` is passed.

Let's see what happens when you call

```
\variationA{Test 1:\\Some Test}
```

This becomes, according to the definition,

```
\variationAInternal{Test 1:\\Some Test}{\commonFunction{Test 1:\\Some Test}}
```

Now your `\variationAInternal` has argument specifiers

```
+m
>{\SplitArgument{1}{;}}m
```

and there is *no* semicolon in the argument. Thus you get

```
\variationAInternalInternal{Test 1:\\Some Test}{\commonFunction{Test 1:\\Some Test}}{-NoValue}\\
```

and so what you eventually obtain is

```
\commonFunction{Test 1:\\Some Test}\\
```

Now let's check

```
\variationB{Test 2:\\Second Test}
```

This transforms into

```
\variationBInternal{Test 2:\\Second Test}{\commonFunction{Test 1:\\Second Test}}
```

and this becomed

```
{\commonFunction{Test 1:\\Second Test}}{-NoValue-}
```

which explains the output. I'm not sure what you're expecting to get; but if you don't use semicolons, no splitting can be done and you always get `-NoValue-` in the second item of the pair of braced groups.

Comment: `\commonFunction` produces (in the first call) the output "45.333pt;11.916pt" [I truncated the numbers].

That is what I'm trying to split with `\SplitArgument`

Comment: @joelproko `\commonFunction` is called last when everything about `\SplitArgument` has already been done. Sorry, but you should explain clearly what you want to achieve. Your approach cannot work.